# Why is GlassFish a lightweight server?

Tags: java, glassfish

I see this terminology used a lot so I'm curious, how is lightweight defined?

> [GlassFish Server Open Source Edition, developed by the GlassFish project open-source community at http://glassfish.java.net/, is the first compatible implementation of the Java EE 6 platform specification. This **lightweight**, flexible, and open-source application server...](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gexaf.html)

Comment: I don't know why, but from personal experience it's definitely not a lightweight server the way it claims. :)

Comment: Elaborated answer to your question: http://alexismp.wordpress.com/2009/07/10/top-reasons-why-glassfish-v3-is-a-lightweight-server/

Comment: It's just advertising. As a technical term appropriate to a computer programming forum, it's a meaningless claim in the absence of an accepted definition.

Comment: tomcat is light weight

Comment: Compared to older application servers, modern ones are certainly lightweight since they start up a lot quicker and use fewer resources. But they're still wickedly complex and huge machines nonetheless.

Comment: @AyushyaDevmurari Tomcat only does a small fraction of what Glassfish gives you out of the box. If you only need a servlet container then Tomcat is a consideration but its not in the same league as Glassfish.

Comment: @Gimby Your description of how light weight can be used to describe modern application servers is pretty good, however, they aren't machines in a hardware sense. They're pieces of software that provide implementations of specs + proprietary value adds. FWIW a lot of the web tier in Glassfish directly descends from Tomcat 5.

Comment: I didn't mean literal machines of course. I should have said complex machinery, I now realize that in the good old days application servers actually were physical machines.

Comment: @NBW Agree its not the full implementation of J2EE specifications but yet it provides whats needed for basic use and thus its light weight